# Change Where NpptoR looks for Rgui.exe

Tags: r

This seems to be a very common problem that has not been solved. When I go to open NpptoR it says it can not find the Rgui.exe file, so I can not run commands from NpptoR in R. I know the problem is that NpptoR is looking in the wrong file directory. My question is, how do I change the file path?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is usually caused b either using an old version of `NPPtoR` (very likely) or `R` (less likely). So I recommend you:

1. Deinstall `NPPtoR`
2. Deinstall `R`
3. Restart your computer
4. Download and install the latest version of `R` from [here](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/).
5. Download and install the latest version of `NPPtoR` from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npptor/).

If this still fails, click with the Right Mouse Button on the `NPPtoR` icon in the taskbar and go to settings, where you can change the folder. But if you have done the aforementioned steps, I am confident you will not need to do so.

Comment: @bstockton, Henrik is exactly correct, unless you have an unusual setup you should not have to mess with the settings in NppToR.  It should 'just work' with any standard setup.  I am one where I have to have a non-standard setup because I am constantly switching between versions of R.  However as much as I love StackOverflow this is not the best place to get help for NppToR.  Try posting at the help forums and I will get notified much earlier that it takes google's crawlers to notify me that someone has posted a question.  Thanks to Henrik for being quick on the answer.

Comment: @Henrik, thanks for the reply but I have tried steps 1-5 multiple times. As many people before me have stated, there is no settings option when you click on the NpptoR icon in the taskbar. It only gives standard options like "Properties" and "Run as administrator". If I could get to the settings menu I'm sure I could change the folder, but I can't get there.

Comment: @AndrewRedd Thanks for the suggestion of taking it to a different source, I will try SourceForge. I have been using NpptoR or a long time and I love it, however when I upgraded to 2.15.1 is when it stopped working.

Comment: It's sounds odd, but my NppToR wasn't giving any error. Instead, it won't let even open R. But after I closed the TeamViewer 9, it worked fine for me.

Comment: after uninstalling notepad++, you might also need to delete the npptor settings file.  on my windows machine, this is located at `C:\Users\anthonyd\AppData\Roaming\NppToR\npptor.ini`